# Missing styles in symbol selector - ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, style-manager

I am trying to add "Transportation" style reference to change the display of my point symbols, but for some reasons I can't. When I am in **Symbol Selector** I select "Style References" and then check in "Transportation", but it doesn't add new symbols to choose from.

When I go to **Style Manager** the "Transportation.style" icon is grayed out, but at the same time I can go into "Marker Symbols" and I can see that symbols are there.

Please see attached picture.

[image]

Am I missing some files? If yes, where could I download them?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be adding this style to your symbology choices in the layer symbology. I don't have a hard and fast answer to that, but as a work-around maybe you can copy the symbols from Transportation into a custom style. The [gray folder indicates read only permissions](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?id=306&pid=302&topicname=Organizing_style_contents).

From the referenced help link:

> You can easily distinguish which style folders contain map elements and symbols, which can be modified, and which are empty: a yellow folder indicates read/write permission, a gray folder indicates read-only permission, and a white folder indicates an empty folder.

Comment: Barrett, thank you for your input. I was able to copy and paste symbols to a different style, but I still wasn't able to see those symbols in Symbol Selector (I could see them in a new style folder in the Style Manager though). Besides copying symbols to existing folder (with write permission) I have also created a new custom style and paste them there - but still no luck... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured that out. I was trying to label the highway with annotation saying "24". The symbol I wanted to use was a shield with "24" number. I didn't realize that my shield symbol was in "Marker Symbol" category, but annotations support only "Text Symbols". Many symbol categories have empty "Text Symbols" folders, that is why no new symbols were added when I was adding new Style Reference...

I should have mention at the beginning that I am working with annotation layer.